# How to save a PDF file in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdf-conversion

I create a pdf file using flowing code. When I run my code the generated pdf file stored in Downloads folder. I want to change this path. I want to save it into my solution. How Can I do this?

Here is the CODE:

```
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(new Rectangle(624f, 568f),0f,0f,0f,0f);
            try
            {
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
                pdfDoc.Open();
                string imageFilePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../images/1.jpg");
                iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageFilePath);

                jpg.ScaleToFit(624f, 468f);
                pdfDoc.Add(jpg);
                pdfDoc.Close();
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";


                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmssff") + ".pdf");

                Response.End(); 

            }
            catch (DocumentException de)
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(de.Message);
            }
```

Comment: When you generate a file on the server and serve it up over HTTP, you dont have any control over where the end user saves it. sorry.

Comment: where are you writing the content? you are missing some code..

Comment: @AnimeshGhosh: Server-side code has no knowledge of the client's file system.  (For lots of very good reasons.)  The client decides where (or even *if*) a file is saved.

Comment: lamkrillin he can still save the file to his local machine he can also generate a unique file name for the .pdf file as well he's missing some Response code as well

Comment: @iamkrillin:: I want to save a specify folder in server where this pdf will save. User can't change this path.  So how can I do this?

Comment: you need to start by doing some research Animesh.. do a simple google search for example key words you can search on are `HTTP Response to save PDF Download` for example here's what I get when I did one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825145/using-http-response-how-to-save-the-pdf-files  moral of the story ..SHOW MORE EFFORT

Comment: @DJKRAZE Doesn't really matter, based on question he wants to change where a file is saved on the *CLIENTS* machine.  Not possible.  Also, hes not missing any code.  Look again

Comment: actually it is possible.. I do it currently when exporting a RadGrid to a .csv or .xls file it will display a save dialog box and the user can either open it.. or save it..

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET: Create CSV and save file on client machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083032/asp-net-create-csv-and-save-file-on-client-machine)

Comment: @DJKRAZE: The behavior you describe further demonstrates that what the OP is asking is *not* possible.  Your RadGrid is prompting the user to save the file, which is expected behavior.  The OP is asking how to write the file directly to the client without prompting the user.  And to force the location of the save on the client's file system.  Thankfully, websites can't do this.

Comment: David.. actually the RadGrid is not doing the Export I had to write me own perhaps I should show an example of what I have done because it's nothing to do with the radGrid.. I could have created any DataSet to read from on the web and no matter where the user is on our system the Response allows them to save the file to a specific location.. so I was thinking that he could follow the same concept with the .pdf file

Answer (score 3):

> I want to save a specify folder in server where this pdf will save.

You can't.  Server-side code does not (and *can not*) know anything about the client-side file system.  This is for a whole host of architectural and security reasons.

> User can't change this path.

They sure can if they're accessing this via a web browser.  Short of writing your own custom web browser, the user can specify where they want to save files.  (Or if they want to save them at all.)

> So how can I do this?

Either write a custom web browser and ask your users to only access your web application from that browser, or write a client-side application for transferring files (and any other functionality you need) and ask your users to use that application instead of their web browser.

Web applications can't access client-side file systems.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use following method

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath()
```

More infor [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/mappath).

Comment: This is not at all related to what the OP is asking